# how to use remote desktop keyboard and mouse events using delphi even if remote desktop window is just closed

Tags: delphi, keyboard, mouse, simulate

i've created a script-like program with Delphi which supposed to click on some desired places and also use keyboard to simulate pressing keys.
the program works just well, but the problem is that if i close the remote connection window with X button or even minimize the remote window, program stops working and wont simulate anything, and resumes after connecting again!!

Comment: The remote session runs in a different session I think.

Comment: Surely all the visible applications run in the same remote session, though, @David. My impression is that Burzum's program is running on the remote computer, driving one or more other programs also on the remote computer. Apparently, the driving stops when the remote desktop connection is disconnected.

Comment: @Rob I think that when you make a new remote connection, a new session is created, or perhaps a new desktop, to host it.

Comment: My take on it is, if the program is trying to simulate clicking on the screen, it can't because there's no screen associated with the session.  The program is still running, but there's no "screen" to click on.  .. But that's just a guess.

Comment: so whats ur suggestion guys? my whole project is depended on this, and i know a program which is working like mine but without this problem!

Comment: And i must mention that i use mouse_event and keybd_event functions, is there any other ways of communication that would solve this problem?

Comment: You can make a script to exit session without disconnect it. You need execute it in remote session when you want exit. Script content: for /l %%x in (1,1,2) do tscon.exe %%x /dest:console exit

Comment: Thank you @Kike but what will happened to the remote itself? i dont think the problem will be solved by this cos as i mentioned i have the problem even if the remote window is minimized not closed!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are running on a target with a post **Win Server 2010**.  There is no console session if no one is logged in.

To run something without a login session, it has to be a **service**.  Similarly, console apps will not work from the startup folder.

Comment: thanks for your help, im using kike Perez's solution and it works to some extend.. but has a problem with more than 3 users logged in